# Function moisture flux convergence?

Tags: function, flux, indices, convergence, metpy

I have to compute several thermodynamic indices and MetPy offers plenty of sounding based parameters (e.g. CAPE, CIN, ...). For the evolution of thunderstorms, the vertically integrated moisture flux convergence is a good predictor. Does MetPy offer functions to compute moisture convergence?

Thanks for help and kind regards,
Alexander

Comment: Not sure this is the best forum for such domain-specific questions, but good luck anyway.

Answer (score 0):

MetPy does have a convergence (technically [divergence](https://unidata.github.io/MetPy/latest/api/generated/metpy.calc.divergence.html#metpy.calc.divergence)) calculation, but there is not currently a calculation for flux, though it is an [open issue](https://github.com/Unidata/MetPy/issues/655) for a feature request and needed for our goal of GEMPAK parity.

Feel free to chime in there to express that this is an important calculation for you. If you get around to implementing it yourself, we'd love you to [contribute](https://unidata.github.io/MetPy/latest/CONTRIBUTING.html) it to MetPy.